# Unamanaged call is not happening from the managed C# code

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I am calling unamanaged function from the managed code. But Unamanaged call is not happening.

**Managed C# code:**
(Created a  project (Sampletest) from Visual C# -> Console App)
Sampletest:

```
namespace Sampletest
{
    class Program
    {
        const string Dllpath2 = @"C:\Users\Sampletest\SampleDll\Debug\SampleDll.dll";
        [DllImport(Dllpath2, EntryPoint = @"IsTherePower", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Boolean IsTherePower();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = IsTherePower();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Unmanaged C++ code:**

(Created a dll project (SampleDll) from Visual C++ -> Windows Desktop -> Dynamic Link Library)

"IsTherePower()" definition is there in SampleDll.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL IsTherePower()
{
    BOOL    bRetValue = FALSE;
    
    return bRetValue;
}
```

But when we are making unmanaged call, first it is going to  dllmain.cpp file present in unmanaged code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

then it is not going to

BOOL IsTherePower() function

and comming back to the managed call at "var test = IsTherePower();"

showing the error "Unhandled exception at 0x7705D6C7 (ntdll.dll) in Sampletest.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction.

**Settings i Made:**

For C# project,

Debug-> Selected "Enable native code debugging"

And I selected "Debug", "x86"

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `IsUPSPresent` using the `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute or use a `.def`-file. Also, to overcome C++ name mangling, your definition has to be `extern "C"` in C++-code.

```
extern "C" {
    BOOL __declspec(dllexport) IsUPSPresent()
    {
        BOOL bRetValue = FALSE;
        return bRetValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added "__declspec(dllexport)" attribute but still seeing the same issue.

Comment: If you didn't declare the function as `extern "C"` its name is still mangled.